# Exim sending email (-53) retry time not reached for any host

Tags: ubuntu, exim

I have problem with some domain in WHM for sending email, only a few special domain names can not send email  to any host(Gmail,Yahoo,...) (it is possible to receive)

But other domains are correct and there is no problem sending
Exim log:

```
2018-05-21 15:57:14 1fKix9-0007MU-FG H=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.199.26] Connection timed out
2018-05-21 15:57:14 1fKix9-0007MU-FG == example@gmail.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out
2018-05-21 15:57:35 1fKix9-0007MU-FG Sender identification U=exampledomain D=exampledomain.com S=email@exampledomain.com
2018-05-21 15:57:35 1fKix9-0007MU-FG == example@gmail.com R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host for 'gmail.co
```